# To remove offset space towards left in MFC Tab Control

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, tabcontrol

Hi I was looking into how I could remove an offset area that is found in the default MFC Tab Control Ex. I have tried using Deflate to the rectangle that holds the Tab, but the issue was the control seemed to in the old location which no coincides with the next Tab,

[image: The Offset space is visible in the left side of Process Tab]

I was able to move the rectangle towards left but the control area of the moved tab is still in its old place, and it seems like only the change happened visually.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/Controls/tcm-setitemsize ?

Comment: Side note: if you are using `CTabCtrl`, you should replace by `CMFCTabCtrl` . Nowadays there is absolutely no advantage to use the first.